# Interprete mobx console outputs

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm stuck with interpreting mobx console outputs. All components are named "observerComponent" in the console output.
Is there a way to enforce a name?

Console Output:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: Cannot update a component (`observerComponent`) while rendering a different component (`observerComponent`). 
at observerComponent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40885:73)
at div
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:12601:62
at div
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:12763:34
at observerComponent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40885:73)
at DndProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:135424:11)
at observerComponent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40885:73)
at observerComponent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40885:73)
at Route (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:107737:29)
at Switch (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:107939:29)
at main
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:14246:25
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:14229:66
at section
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:14262:63
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:14229:66
at section
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:14262:63
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:14229:66
at observerComponent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40885:73)
at App (http://localhost:4200/main.js:277:76)
at Router (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:107368:30)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:106988:35)
```

Component:

```
const GenericEditor = observer(() => {
   /**/
});

export default GenericEditor;
```

//edit

https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#displayname
Does not work for console outputs from react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`displayName`](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging)

```
export const MyComponent = observer(function MyComponent(props) {
    return <div>hi</div>
})
MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent'
```

Comment: Works within the message (  Cannot update a component (`CollectionEditor`)  ) but not for the stack trace (  at observerComponent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40442:73) ) 

Not perfect but works for me